# Sharepoint 2010. How do I export list in a feature to sharepoint application with MSVS?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have to use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 with standard Sharepoint 2010 project templates.

When I try to create a simple sharepoint feature that has only one list inside itself, feature is published, imported, activated - but list I declared is missed in Sharepoint.

I can't figure out why my list is missed.

What I do step by step:

1. MSVS. New Sharepoint 2010 project (Farmed solution)
2. MSVS. Add net item - new Sharepoint List
3. MSVS. Create a feature. Make sure that my list is inside feature
4. MSVS. Publish project to wsp file locally
5. SP. Import wsp. No error are found
6. SP. Activate feature - feature is activated

There is no new custom list in Sharepoint after that.

I double checked that wsp file has standard schema.xml, elements.xml for my list.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Have you checked list templates gallery? Can you see you list template there?

Comment: No, there isn't. What's interesting here - when I Deploy project to SP, it's deployed successfully and I can observe list in SP

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the order you are adding items to project.

Check that your list definition is in the feature definition. When you add list after the feature to project list will be added to feature automatically.

Also check that the feature is in solution.

Comment: Thank you, Mazin. Feature is in the solution, and list definition as well as list instance are inside feature. What is interesting here - when I deploy project to SP, I can observe list inside SP

Comment: So you are missing the list or list template? List template might be marked as hidden. Check Hidden attribute in template definition. Do you have list template definition in your project and feature? Or you just added list instance to the project. In this case only list will be deployed.